# Allow option to select primary tag in question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Currently when selecting some tags in a question, one of them becomes the, as I like to call it, 'primary tag'.

This tag will also show in the title of the page.

Take for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696087/ionic-components-count-design-limitations). The question is clearly mainly about the ionic framework but the page title will say `svg - ....` and `svg` is also shown as the first tag in the question.

Isn't it a good idea to let the user decide in what order they want the tags?

Comment: An extra option is IMHO a little bit overkilled. Maybe the primary tag will be the first one which is added?

Comment: I think it's alphabetical

Comment: @Paulie_D: it's sorted by number of questions for the tag. So svg is the more populous tag (25k+ questions), followed by ionic2 (almost 10k), etc.

Comment: I want to say "no" simply because most people are already bad at using tags appropriately.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but f.i. my question about Java and Eclipse, gets the Eclipse tag, why is that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584954/reference-file-in-jar-with-plain-java-file

Comment: @Ivaro18: because the title includes the word 'java' in it.